# Pkcs12Store without constructor

Tags: digital-signature, itext7, pkcs#12

Good morning. I have been trying for many days to transfer my signature process, which used iTextSharp, to iText7.
The main error it gives me is when trying to use Pkcs12Stores, because it tells me that it does not contain a constructor. And indeed looking at the code of the integrated packages, that class does not have a constructor. How is it possible? What package do I have to install?

I have tried itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter, itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter, BouncyCastle.Cryptography... and I can't find it.
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Not only the iText API changed since the iTextSharp times, also the APIs of dependencies, in this case BouncyCastle. Their current API provides a `Pkcs12StoreBuilder` for `Pkcs12Store` building. You may want to look at [these examples](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.signing-examples.simple-test/iText/SigningExamples/Simple/TestSignBCSimple.cs) from the github iText .NET simple signing samples.

Comment: Solved. I created the instance like this:
Pkcs12Store pks = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();